# Programatically generate graphical (ADAPT) models / diagrams of structured data

Tags: svg, drupal-7, diagram, dynamically-generated, activiti

I am searching for strategies or other starting points to generate diagrams from structured data stored in a database. To make a simplified example that would be very similar to my requirements:

```
Input:          DDL SQL to create tables with attributes in a Database.
Desired output: ERD diagram of the tables with connections to each other as svg.
```

The type of diagram I want to build is [ADAPT](http://www.symcorp.com/downloads/ADAPT_white_paper.pdf) but since I'm sure there is no implementation that directly generates ADAPT diagrams I'd be happy with anything that can generate models like BPMN, EPK or something similar. A generator for ERD might be a start but since ADAPT is more complex than ERD it would require heavy customization.

I currently create a prototype using [Drupal](http://drupal.org/) so something in that area would be nice but I am glad with any input where I can learn about solving the core problem: *How to automatically create graphical models out of structured data (without data about or user interaction in terms of element placement, element size etc.)?*

**Sidenotes:**

- svg is no hard requirement (could be png etc) but seems the best option to me.
- The application I am building records requirenments that then should become the models.
- The solution needs to be integratable into a web application. (have some sort of api)
- [Activiti](http://activiti.org/) could be a base for the diagram drawing but I cannot find information about diagramm creation via API instead of the UI.
- [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) might be a starting point but I haven't seen any work beyond ERD.
- This is for a student project so the budget is limited.

Comment: How to get from structured data to an ADAPT diagram is an extremely specific question. One that most likely no one can answer because there is none. So how should I as such a question without broadening it?
My question was asking for strategies to get from a structured data to graphical models. Any suggestion was welcome. I received helpful answers and you had nothing better to do than to close the question because I wrote that I'd also be interested in tools or libraries as starting point. You even went so far as to downvote the answers - WTF?

Answer (score 1):

There is a number of diagramming libraries available and each have their strengths and weaknesses. It strongly depends on your exact requirements. I suggest you evaluate some of the alternatives and see what suits you best.

*What I think*: **In a commercial scenario**, the  [yFiles](http://www.yworks.com) suite of libraries for various platforms is probably an option. From what I can see the HTML/JavaScript based solution should satisfy your requirements quite well: It can easily be told to fetch the data from various input sources, automatically create the structure and most importantly calculate a layout for the diagram so that it can be viewed immediately without having to be arranged by hand. Also you can customize the library to a very high degree: you can make the items look like the ones in "ADAPT", customize user interactivity so that only valid model changes are allowed (if you need interactive editing), and of course do all of this programmatically using a flexible Javascript API.

There is a nice example of that capability here:
[Interactive Graph Source](http://live.yworks.com/yfiles-for-html/demos/DataBinding/demo.yfiles.binding.interactivegraphsource/index.html)

Full disclosure: I work for yWorks, however on Stackoverflow I do not represent my employer.

Comment: Thank you Sebastian. I use yEd which is an awesome tool and didn't know you had such advanced web based editors. The software I am developing is part of my bachelors thesis so I'd be willing to invest some money in good software to built upon but the 2.640 € for the academic yFiles for HTML single developer licence are out of my budget for the barely two months of use.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/)' DOT language and then run Graphviz' DOT.exe program by command line, which inputs a DOT language file and outputs an .svg file.  This approach is pretty simple since you don't need to use Graphviz by API, and instead, just generate text file from whatever your programming environment is.

Not sure if this help you at all; perhaps just the general idea may be useful.

Going further, though, I've done this in an open source project, with the salient differences from what you're specifically describing above being that my project takes tabular (self-describing, structured) data instead of SQL DDL as its user input.  Output is information in the form of concepts and relationships that can be used in several ways (searched, manipulated, diagrammed), one of which is to generate an .svg output showing various colored and shaped entities interconnected by variously colored and labeled arrows.  The .svg output is done by translating concepts and relationships into an appropriate DOT file and then running Graphviz by command line, and then launching Firefox on the .svg output.  Lots of differences from what you need, still, layout is handled purely by Graphviz.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience and code. The SQL DDL was just an example. I'll have the information in a structured way so in that concern it's somewhat similar to what you have developed. The biggest difference I believe is that I target for more complex shapes (ADAP). I guess GraphViz is the best option I've got. Since your code might help me to get started I'll award your answer the bounty.

Comment: ok, check out the QuickRDA project on github.